# How to get combobox value at select function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) with [select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event defined:

```
  $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
      var self = this,
        select = this.element.hide(),
        selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
      var input = this.input = $( "<input>" )
        .insertAfter( select )
        .val( value )
        .autocomplete({
          delay: 0,
          minLength: 0,              
          source: ...

          select: function( event, ui ) {
            // 
          },
        })
```

I can get combobox value at `select` function with `ui.item.value`, but if I try to get the same by combobox id - `$( "#cbCity" ).val()`, I always receive initial value. I can not (?) use `ui.item.value` here, since this function is defined for 3 comboboxes and at select function I need to get values for all of them:

```
$( "#cbCountry" ).val()+'-'+$( "#cbCity" ).val()+'-'+$( "#cbOrg" ).val()
```

Please see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/k2J5v/2/).

Looks like I have to generate select options dynamically at select function:

```
<option value="value">label</option>
```

and then mark them as selected as it was done in the initial code:

```
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
      item: ui.item.option
    });
  }
```

But I am not sure how to do it - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/k2J5v/4/.

Comment: For the items already selected, you can use `$('#cbCountry').next().val()`.

Comment: @hyperslug, it works, but looks like it gets the value from the input, not from the select. So it will return text value of the input, not the select option value.

Comment: Why not store the full text in the `success` callback: `value: item.label`?

Comment: @hyperslug, how can it help me with the question I've asked?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over each item selected in the combobox.  For example:

```
var test_arr = new Array();
    $("#test1 option:selected").each(function() {
        test_arr.push( $(this).val() );
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wblakenc/3xMn)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like jsfiddle link is incorrect. And I don't think that such approach will help me since actually I don't have any `option` added (values are read from the remote source and `<option ...` is not addedto the page)